# Why isn't the CSS property 'line-height' letting me make tight line-spaces in Chrome?

Tags: minimum, css

I have a paragraph tag that I defined elsewhere with a line height of 15px, and I have another paragraph tag further down the page where I want to make the line height around 10px. Funny thing is, it won't let me get down to 10px or anything smaller than that, but when I set it to 25px or higher, the line-height property seems to be working.

I checked the relevant CSS (all hand-coded) via the Chrome browser's web developer tools (Chrome's version of Firefox's Firebug) and couldn't find anything relevant. Is there a common CSS bug that prevents me from shrinking the line-height beyond a certain minimum amount?

Comment: have you tried something like `{line-height: 0.75em}` it works fine for me.

Comment: Agreed, mhenry's answer definitely deserves the win on this.

Answer (score -12, accepted):

line-height is relative to font-size, you can't go any lower than that unless you declare negative margin.

Comment: False, you can set `line-height: 0.5` and your text will overlap.  You can even set it to `0`.

Answer (score 80):

I've noticed in both Firefox and Chrome that if you set the HTML5 doctype there's a minimum line-height for inline elements.  For block elements you can set the line-height to whatever you want, even make the lines overlap.

If you don't set the HTML5 doctype, there's no minimum line-height for either block or inline elements.

Comment: Right on. If you have a `span`, for example, setting it to `display:block` solves this issue. Although I wonder if this is an intended feature of the html5 standard. It seems very messy to me.

Comment: This should be the approved answer. Realizing this solved my problem.

Comment: That's too bad, I want a tighter line-height while keeping `display:inline` and HTML5. Any other ideas maybe?

Comment: `display: inline-block;` also works, at least on Chrome, and preserves the best of `display: inline;` and `display: block;`, including this feature.

Comment: This is a perfect example why answers with highest number of upvotes should appear above accepted answer.

Comment: I'd assume this behaviour is because `line-height` makes more sense on block-level elements. It would be inapplicable to only a specific section of a paragraph. In my case I had an `<a>` tag inside of a `<p>` and setting `line-height` on the `<a>` had no effect. The working solution was to set it on the enclosing `<p>` element.

Answer (score 30):

I ran into the same issue, worked well with:

```
.element { display: block; line-height: 1.2; }
```

Answer (score 6):

After testing this in IE 8-11, Firefox 38.0.1, and Chrome 43, the behavior is the same: inline elements have a minimum line-height that they won't go below. It appears this minimum height comes from the [CSS spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-line-height):

> On a block container element whose content is composed of inline-level elements, 'line-height' specifies the minimal height of line boxes within the element. The minimum height consists of a minimum height above the baseline and a minimum depth below it, exactly as if each line box starts with a zero-width inline box with the element's font and line height properties. We call that imaginary box a "strut."

If you want to maintain some benefits of inline elements, you can use `display: inline-block`. You can also use `display: block`. Both will allow you to make the line-height whatever you want in all the browsers I tested.

Two related questions for more reading:

[why the span's line-height is useless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11829393/why-the-spans-line-height-is-useless)

[The browser seems to have a minimum line-height on this block that contains text. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14945260/the-browser-seems-to-have-a-minimum-line-height-on-this-block-that-contains-text)