# Why can't I decrease the line-height of this text?

Tags: css, font-size

http://jsfiddle.net/mJxn4/

This is very odd: I have a few lines of text wrapped in an `<em>` tag. No matter what I do, lowering the value for `line-height` below 17px has no effect. I can bump the `line-height` *up* to greater than 17px and it'll apply, but I can't get it lower than 17px.

The CSS in question is:

```css
#others .item em {
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 17px;
}
```

Try adjusting the line height both higher and lower and run the updated fiddle after each change, and you'll see what I mean.

Why would this be? No `line-height` is specified anywhere else in the CSS, so nothing is overriding it. That couldn't be the case anyway because I'm adjusting the `line-height` up and down *within the same selector*, so it doesn't make sense that a higher value would apply, but a lower value would get overridden.

Comment: I started with local HTML/CSS first; then I extracted just the piece that I was having the issue with and posted on JSFiddle, and that appears the same way. Could it be the browser? I'm using Safari.

Comment: I think, it's working fine, you can put the line-height: 40px to see the different since with font-size: 13 and line-height: 17, it looks similar.

Comment: @mtr The OP already said it was possible to increase it, just not decrease it.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7424867/why-isnt-the-css-property-line-height-not-letting-me-make-really-tight-line-s

Answer (score 133, accepted):

Because the `em` tag is inline and its line-height cannot be lower than its parent `div`.

For example, if you set the line-height of the parent to 10px, then you would be able to decrease the line-height of `em` tag to 10px as well.

Comment: But the parent (`#others .item`) doesn't have a `line-height` in my example. Does it just go by the browser default `line-height` then?

Comment: the default line-height is set to auto.

Comment: Ah, you're right: by specifying a lower `line-height` on the parent, I can lower the `em`'s `line-height` to that same value.

Comment: Wow, I've been working with CSS for a _long_ time and did not know that.

Answer (score 56):

In order for line-height property to work, div should has display property equal to block

```
.app-button-label{
    line-height: 20px;
    display: block;
 }
```

Comment: display: inline-block, of course, also works (better for some designs)

Answer (score 14):

I was facing this problem with divs in mobile view - the line height was way too big and line-height wasn't working! I managed to make it work by adding "display:block", per advice here: [Why isn't the CSS property 'line-height' letting me make tight line-spaces in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7424867/why-isnt-the-css-property-line-height-not-letting-me-make-really-tight-line-s)

Hope this helps anyone else facing the same problem in future

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using `normalized css` option in jsfiddle - **which equates to the CSS rules being reset** - ala http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

You can either reset the reset, or use a different reset if you really need it.

See here for more details:

http://sixrevisions.com/css/a-comprehensive-guide-to-css-resets/

Answer (score 0):

**The best way to do it is using css reset.**

Write your own or use popular one like

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the block level elements(h1, h2, h3...h6,div) sets the minimum line-height for its inline children elements(span, em etc.). Which means if there is a  element inside  (with line-height 1.5), then the  can set minimum line-height of 1.5 and no less than it.

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way is to specify the line height with a higher priority, for example you could write: line-height: 14px !important;

If it is still not working set high priority in both where you u would like to decrease the line height (inline css) and also put in the body css .. remember the high priority (!important;) because it overrides any other unknown css rules.

Hope this helps

Ahmed